# SVN: Mismatch of log/lock name and login name

Tags: apache, svn, unreal-engine4, centrify

Our current SVN repo is on an Ubuntu 14.04.3 that authenticates through an Active Directory domain. The server uses CentrifyDC (express) for AD integration.

SVN is through Apache 2.4.7, WebDAV/SVN. Authenticated with ldap from the AD.

The issue is that while login works great, with (example) 'fredj' and a password, when SVN issues locks and marks logs it uses 'fredj@school.edu'.

Not a huge issue, until we started using software (Unreal Engine 4) that verifies locks with the login name, not the domain appended name. The mismatch is causing complete failure of the vendor package.

I have been searching a solution; on the vendor site, documentation for Apache, SVN, the WebDAV module, the SVN module, no joy.

I'm looking for any configuration option (SVN, Apache, Centrify?) to match the name the SVN server marks the lock, with what the user login name is.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to do that other than hack the svn source control provider to had a new configuration option.

You don't even have to rebuild the whole engine, you can extract the plugin as a project plugin that will override the default engine one. Then you can submit your mod to Epic Games.

I know that because I faced the same issue with my Git LFS 2 Lock support, as well as for the Plastic SCM plugin.

Cheers!